# Ionic how to run function of a page from another page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have 2 pages. What i need is when i click button on of page i need to run function of other page. Basically 1 is page and other is popup. I need when user click on button of popup the page function will run.

```
 export class Page {
     constructor() {}

     callthis(){
       console.log('abc');
     }
  }

   export class popup{
    constructor() {}

      click(){
          here need to call that callthis();
      }
  }
```

I know possible by creating a service but not want to do it by service

Comment: Why would you want to do this?
use rxjs instead

Comment: page showing popup and click popbutton need to run a function which is in page class

Answer (score 0):

run it second page **ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit() {
    yourFunction();
  }
```